# How to use Web app payment gateaway in android application?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment, android-webservice

I am developing an android app that is related to open-cart application type.

This application was already developed in web app. It's already having a payment gateway option in web app. so i am just use that payment gateway option into my android application.

So any one can give me an idea how to use the existing payment gateway in to my app?

when I did Google, I got one solution is by using the web view we can solve this issue. When I asked the PHP developer who developed the website, he said that I was simply call the URL of payment gateway and passing the four parameters as hidden fields.

But the problem is how we can pass the parameters to the web view's URL? and how we can get the response from the web view payment is success or not?or ask the php developer to write a webservices?

Please give me an idea how can i do that?

Comment: Have you done any research on this problem before posting a question? Which concrete problems have you faced in that research? Currently your question is too broad, and cannot be answered in SO format. Please read this before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Haspemulator  i am asking just an idea, how can i use that already existing payment gateway in to android app?

Comment: I understand what you're asking, and I maintain such questions don't really fit the StackOverflow. You need to show what you have already done to solve your problem. If you have done nothing yet, you better do your research in some other place, and return on StackOverflow if you'll face some *concrete* problem. You'll be able to get a much better answer in that case.

Comment: @Somanadh have you got the idea about the implementation of payment gateway.

Comment: @Illusion i am solving this issue by the help of web services and finally load that webservice's url into webview.

Comment: @Somanadh thanks for reply, webview shows the web content but I want to show the response that user transaction is success/failure in my application, Unable to fetch that data from webview. please help.

Comment: @illusion It is a simple logic, In web based application's payment gateway after successful of payment, it redirects to the another url or our site url, so here we are loading the web payment gateway into webview, By creating our webview client class extends WebViewClient in this  we should override a method call shouldOverrideUrlLoading(Url url) by using this we can get which url is loaded into webview. add this class object to your webview using setWebViewClient().

Comment: when i implement redirection method using WebViewClient, on OTP page when switch to message app for get OTP and switch again my app to put that OTP, then my web page restart from starting...Please help.
NOTE: This issue occur in android version 6 or heigher...